# Python turtle user input

Tags: python, if-statement, input, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to write some code that when the user inputs a shape the turtle draws it, this is what I have so far but it just draws a pentagon all the time

```
    import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')

def triangle():
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/3)


def square():
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/4)

def pentagon():
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/5)


answer = input('pick a shape.. triangle, square or pentagon')
if answer ==('triangle'):
    triangle()

elif answer == ('square'):
    square()

elif answer == ('pentagon'):
    pentagon()

else:
    print ('wrong input')
```

Comment: [tag:turtle] is a RDF language. Use [tag:turtle-graphics] for these kind of questions

Comment: The shapes draw just fine on my machine. Are you sure this is the code that you're actually running?

Comment: def doesn't work on mine, no mater what shape I input it just says wrong input

Comment: thanks just realised the mistake, i was pressing space before entering the shape.

Comment: See also [`textinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput) for collecting input. Users might not know to look at the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate your data from your code a bit more and go with something like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

DISTANCE = 100

def polygon(turtle, sides):
    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(DISTANCE)
        turtle.right(360 / sides)

shapes = { \
    'triangle': lambda turtle: polygon(turtle, 3), \
    'square': lambda turtle: polygon(turtle, 4), \
    'pentagon': lambda turtle: polygon(turtle, 5), \
}

shape = input('Pick a shape: ' + ", ".join(shapes) + ': ')

if shape in shapes:

    yertle = Turtle(shape='turtle')

    shapes[shape](yertle)

    screen = Screen()
    screen.exitonclick()

else:
    print('Bad input!')
```

If you're uncomfortable with the `lambda` statements, you can simply do:

```
def triangle(turtle):
    polygon(turtle, 3)
...
shapes = { \
    'triangle': triangle,
    ...
}
```

for each shape you want to implement.

Answer (score -2):

Hey You can try below code:

```
import turtle
def triangle():
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/3)


def square():
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/4)

def pentagon():
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(360/5)

turtle.shape('turtle')
answer = raw_input('pick a shape.. triangle, square or pentagon: ')

print(answer)

if answer ==('triangle'):
    triangle()

elif answer == ('square'):
    square()

elif answer == ('pentagon'):
    pentagon()

else:
    print ('wrong input')
```